# How to draw SharpDX 2D Bitmap Outline

Tags: c#, directx, sharpdx

i want drawing bitmap outline

**Now Drawing**

---

```
Device.DrawBitmap(mBitmap, GetBound(), Opacity, d2.BitmapInterpolationMode.Linear);

// mBitmap as SharpDX.Direct2D1.Bitmap

// GetBound() as Bitmap Bound
```

---

[image]
[image]